# Custom Field data only shows after manual post update

Tags: custom-field, automatic-updates

I have a custom field [address] that converts a street address and displays it on a google map on the front end post.

Upon manual post update, the latitude and longitude address co-ordinates populate correctly into the [address] custom field and hey presto, the Google Map shows up on the front end post.

**The problem I have is this:**

The [address] custom field is being populated by an import script (wp-allimport) which updates my posts via daily cron, from a master file.

The cron import update works fine for all post details (e.g. date, images etc), except for the [address] custom field.  It does populate the [address] custom field correctly, but the Google Map does not show on the front end.

I believe this is because the post needs to be updated a second time in order for the latitude and longitude co-ordinates to "stick".

**How can I rectify this?  I have several thousand posts that are updated daily, so doing it manually is not an option!**

Things I've tried:
I also read these related posts but didn't see anything conclusive.
[Automate post update for all posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20714/automate-post-update-for-all-posts)
(I tried Bainternet's suggested code, which simply outputted the custom field data, but  but not as the geo-coded map)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297486/render-google-map-in-wordpress-based-on-address-custom-field?rq=1

Comment: Does your site use any kind of caching?

Comment: no, i'm not using any special cache control.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved this by re-installing WP.  It seems there was some kind of corruption which was resolved after a fresh install.